# Vertical drop down Navigation issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I'm working on making a horizontal desktop navigation responsive. I've changed it to be displayed horizontally on smaller screens but now I have the issue with the drop down submenus, as they cover the parent items underneath. Instead I want the other parent items to be pushed underneath the dropdown.
So something like [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Super-Smooth-Accordion-Dropdown-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3/)

Is it possible to achieve this without jQuery? the people the website is for want to avoid using any more jQuery.

Comment: Your really need to post the code you're trying to debug here!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code i'm just guessing here...

Try making your dropdown menus relative positioned.

```
.sub-menu {position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time help for the this resources[http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_menu.asp]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,I've sorted it with setting the height to 100% and changing the position to relative